# Can not control div html content using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Although I think that I did it before successfully, but this code does not work correctly this time.

The idea I need to perform is to check if **tabheader div** is showed, then replace (+) string with (-) and vice versa when div is **tabheader div** is hidden.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div>
    <div class="tabheader" value="1">
        <p> + sea food </p>
    </div>
    <div id="content_1" class="tabcontent">
        hi all 11111
    </div>
    <div class="tabheader" value="2">
        <p> + pizza </p>
    </div>
    <div id="content_2" class="tabcontent">
        hi all 222222
    </div>
    <div class="tabheader" value="3">
        <p> + sandwitches </p>
    </div>
    <div id="content_3" class="tabcontent">
        hi all 33333
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
}
.tabheader {
    height: 24px;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #B2BBD0;
    margin: 18px;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
}
```

javascript code

```
$('.tabheader').click(function() { 
    $('#content_'+$(this).attr("value")).toggle("slow"); 
    var header_content = $(this).html(); 
    if($(this).toggle()) {
        header_content = header_content.replace("+","-"); 
        $(this).html(header_content);  
    }
    else {
        header_content = header_content.replace(/\-/g,"+"); 
        $(this).html("header_content");  
    }
});
```

The problem that when I click on **tabheader div**, it disappears! Can anybody tell me where's the problem?

Comment: What is $(this).toggle() doing? You need a function that returns true or false.

Comment: I thought that can return true if $(this) is toggled while I can use .toggle(showOrHide) correctly. can you tell me how to detect if $(this).toggle status ?

Comment: Your code had multiple issues. Firstly, the if condition checking for return value of toggle (if always returns non-falsy value). Secondly, you probably dont want to be toggling the visibility of the tabheader, i believe you only wanted to replace + with - in the headers and vice versa.

Comment: @techfoobar I already fix my code with just search about any (+) or (-) and replace it. but i really need to know how to check current toggle status for my personal knowledge.

Comment: To know if an element is visible, you can use $(element).is(':visible') in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.tabheader').click(function() { 
    var content = $('#content_'+$(this).attr("value"));
    var header_content = $(this).html(); 
    if(content.is(':visible')) {
        header_content = header_content.replace(/\-/g,"+");
        $(this).html(header_content);
    }
    else {
        header_content = header_content.replace("+","-");
        $(this).html(header_content);
    }
    $('#content_'+$(this).attr("value")).toggle("slow");
});
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wNsMs/1/

I believe this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line in your else condition:

```
 $(this).html("header_content");
```

to:

```
 $(this).html(header_content);
```

Comment: No, still the same problem. Please try it by yourself and help me to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this line is actually toggling your div to not visible which is why it goes away.

```
 if($(this).toggle()) {
```

what you want is to test if it is currently visible or not like this:

```
if($('#content_'+$(this).attr("value")).is(":visible")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

line 6: if($(this).toggle()) do not make sense, $(this).toggle() return the this object itself. And it toggle the header div instead of the content div.

and $(this).html("header_content"); should not be a string in it.

And when toggle with "slow", the div state won't change right away, so it would be better check the content div status before calling the toggle.

Here is the updated script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $('.tabheader').click(function() {
       var header_content = $(this).html();
       if($('#content_'+$(this).attr("value")).css("display")=='none')
       {
           header_content = header_content.replace("+","-");
           $(this).html(header_content);
       }
       else{
           header_content = header_content.replace("-","+");
           $(this).html(header_content);
       }

       $('#content_'+$(this).attr("value")).toggle("slow");
});
</script>
```